# What does this Chai statement mean?

Tags: javascript, chai

> Chai asserts what data should be available to a test when it runs.

I don't really understand what this mean. I assume that it is what the input is plugged it for lets say a function that is then compared by some equal terminology to thee expected value?

Comment: can you give more context? I might be able to guess but I don't want to guess wrong.

Comment: It's a question and I'm supposed to say its true or false.

"What does it mean to say that Chai is an assertion (or expectation) library?"
I  believe it's false but I'm a bit confused as Chai doesn't provide data - it just is an assertion function in the end

Comment: If it's a question, then I'm tempted to say "false" but mostly because, as you yourself observed, it doesn't actually make much sense - Chai, as with any other testing library, will test what you tell it to. It's perfectly valid to have tests without having data. Not all functionality needs to be provided with input. However, I'm not sure if whoever asked that question doesn't have some something else in mind